# Javascript : How do I achieve this execution order?

Tags: javascript

I have something like this.

```
function a() {
  ajax(callback_function);
}

callback_function() {
  // done!, called after ajax is finished
}

function b() {
  a();
  c();  // make sure c is executed AFTER a is finished.
}

function c() {
  // called after a()!
}
```

How do I make sure that the function c() is called AFTER a() is finished? I think I have to use another callback function, but unsure of what to do.

EDIT

Didn't make it clear. I'd prefer if I didn't call c() inside my callback_function since a() can be called without needing to call c().

Comment: If you call b() then your code currently works exactly as you're describing that you want it to work. If you however need to call c() after callback_function() then just call it at the end of callback_function().

Comment: _How do I make sure that the function c() is called AFTER a() is finished?_ In your example `c()` is always called after `a()` is finished. Did you mean: _How do I make sure that the function c() is called AFTER `callback_function()` is finished_?

Comment: In case you use jQuery, have a look at [deferred objects](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-objec). There are also other implementations around which you can use without jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can wrap all your callbacks into an anonymous function :

```
function a(callback) {
    ajax(function(){
        callback_function();
        callback();
    });
}

callback_function() {
  // done!, called after ajax is finished
}

function b() {
  a(c);
   // make sure c is executed AFTER a is finished.
}

function c() {
  // called after a()!
}
```

or you could register another callback to your `callback_function` :

```
function a(callback) {
  ajax(function(){
    callback_function(callback);
});
}

callback_function(callback) {
  // done!, called after ajax is finished
  callback();
}

function b() {
  a(c);
   // make sure c is executed AFTER a is finished.
}

function c() {
  // called after a()!
}
```

A more elegant (and better) way is to bind callbacks to a certain custom event such as "ajax-done" and after the ajax code successfully executes, you can trigger that specific event.
If you use jquery, the event-method is quite simple :

```
function a() {
  ajax(function(){
    $(window).trigger('ajax-done');
  });
}

callback_function() {
  // done!, called after ajax is finished
}

function b() {
  a();
   // make sure c is executed AFTER a is finished.
}

function c() {
  // called after a()!
}
$(window).bind('ajax-done',callback_function);
$(window).bind('ajax-done',c);
```

Of course you can do the same thing without jquery, but it's a bit messier since you have to make sure that your code is cross-browser.

Answer (score 1):

You could call c() from your callback function

Comment: can I do it without calling c() within my callback function?

Comment: you could use a synchronous ajax request, but I wouldn't recommand it because it would freeze the browser.

Answer (score 1):

You can rework `a` so it takes a callback function as a parameter.  That way, you can call it for the scenario where `c` needs to be called after and where it doesn't need to be called:

```
function a(callback) {
    ajax(callback);
}

function callback_function() { }

function b() {
    a(function() {
        callback_function();
        c();
    });
}

function b2() {
    a(callback_function);
}

function c() { }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to tie your callback with calling `c()` directly you have 2 options:

1.Either change `a` to this:

```
function a(fn) {
    ajax(function() {
        callback_function();
        if (fn) fn();
    });
}
```

And now you have:

```
function b() {
    a(c);
}
```

2.Add a signal at the end of callback_function:

```
function callback_function() {
    // ...
    emit('callback_done', { param1: true, param2, false });
}

function b() {
    connect('callback_done', c);
    a();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to create another callback, simply call the `c` function in the end of `callback` function

```
function a() {
  ajax(callback_function);
}

callback_function() {
  // Do whatever you need with data from ajax
  c();
}

function b() {
  a();
}

function c() {
  // called after a()!
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood what you're trying to do properly, you could use an anonymous function for this particular case, which means you won't have to modify or duplicate your callback function:

```
function a() {
    ajax(function() {
        callback_function();
        c();
    });
}
function callback_function() {}
function c() {}
```